# Why is Foursquare API not returning menu for certain venues

Tags: api, foursquare

I am hoping someone can figure this out:

Through the Foursquare API, you can get the menu by providing the Venue_ID of a particular restaurant:

- https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/menu

e.g. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/47a1bddbf964a5207a4d1fe3/menu?oauth_token=my_auth_token_goes_here&v=20130928

And that works.

But it doesn't work for the following (and several other) restaurants:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4fa027ede4b0e4be23b3374e/menu?oauth_token=my_auth_token_goes_here&v=20130928

- This gives me a response back but the menu is empty! :(

You can confirm by trying it out at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4fa027ede4b0e4be23b3374e/menu

Would appreciate any help/insights on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foursquare is only allowed to redistribute menu data from certain providers through its public API. Unfortunately you've stumbled upon an example of this. If `count` inside the `menus` object is `0`, you should handle this situation gracefully.