# Foursquare - Less number of menus are displayed in venues 'Good Stuff Diner' in API Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, foursquare

We have searched the venues 'Good Stuff Diner' in foursquare website and it displayed the venues 'Good Stuff Diner'.

FYI, Please see the url:

> https://foursquare.com/v/good-stuff-diner/4a1b592ef964a520ee7a1fe3

From the above url, we have clicked the link 'View Menu' to visit all the menus for the venues 'Good Stuff Diner'.

Please see all the menus from this url:

> https://foursquare.com/v/good-stuff-diner/4a1b592ef964a520ee7a1fe3/menu

for the venues 'Good Stuff Diner'.

By using the above search we have got the venue id `4a1b592ef964a520ee7a1fe3`.

**Displaying less number of menus for the venues 'Good Stuff Diner' in API Explorer:**

We have used the endpoints `venues/VENUE_ID/menu` to get the menus for the venues 'Good stuff diner'(4a1b592ef964a520ee7a1fe3) in API Explorer window but we didn't get more number of menus as it is in the manual search.

> **Can anyone please assist our request why the menus results are very less in api explorer for the above endpoints and give us the steps to do for some other way to get 'all menus' as it is shown in manual search.**

Thanks,

Bargavi

Comment: Don't exclude the possibility that it might be a bug on their end. Try passing in parameters like count/rows/pages to see if that changes.

Comment: Also found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19080504/854698